# Generate post id in url

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

Is there a way that I can generate the id profile id. for example instead of having ***localhost/lary/quickstart/public/profile/35/edit*** I want to have ***localhost/lary/quickstart/public/profile/habb778/edit*** here is my code

```
public function edit($companyname)
{
    $pro=Profile::find($companyname);
    return view('layouts.profileedit')->with('pro',$pro);
}

<a href="{{url('profileedit',$use->companyname)}}" style="color:#F88B22;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::resource('profile','ProfileController',['except'=>'edit']);
Route::get('profileedit/{companyname}','ProfileController@edit');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the resolution logic of a model in your routes by hooking into the `boot` method of the `RouteServiceProvider`

```
Route::bind('profile', function($value) {
    if (is_int($value)) {
        return Profile::findOrFail($value);
    } else {
        return Profile::where('string_column', $value)->firstOrFail();
    }
});
```

Some variation of that will work. Then you can call the following:

```
{{route('profile.edit', $use->string_column}}
```

Replace `string_column` with whatever column you want to compare your string against in your table.

Comment: Before I try your answer I'm going to show you what I did. I am going to update my question

Comment: I edited it I am getting an error message here saying Trying to get property 'companyname' of non-object